# How do I create a function that will create and place a button, with tkinter, based in input values in the argument?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying make a python function that will take in arguments, and create a button from tkinter.

Some background, this is for a larger project with a lot of buttons being used, and the purpose of this is to increase efficiency when adding new button. I also wanted a central place where I can change a small variable to switch around every button at once instead of having to adjust every single button command.

So pieces that I am using in the larger project to create the tkinter window are being used, which includes some add ball bits and pieces.

That main way I have chosen to place buttons location is based on x, y points, I know there are easier ways, however this is just have I have chosen to do it.

The current problem is what then I run the code, the button is created, however the button is not responsive and the function the button would run when pressed, runs(which shouldn't be happening). As in the command doesn't run, but the button shows its being pressed when clicked on the tkinter window.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

winWidth = 500
winHeight = 500

HEIGHT = 30
WIDTH = 100
SIZE = 15
PHOTO = PhotoImage(
    file=r"C:\\Users\\Paint\\VS Code\\1x1 pixel.png", width=1, height=1)

screeenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

cenX = int(screeenWidth/2 - winWidth/2)
cenY = int(screenHeight/2 - winHeight/2)

root.geometry(f'{winWidth}x{winHeight}+{cenX}+{cenY}')
root.title('Button Testing')

def Create_Button(BUTTON : str, Text : str, Command, Width : int, Height : int, x : int, y: int):
    BUTTON = Button(
        root, 
        text = Text, 
        command = Command, 
        width = WIDTH + Width, 
        height = HEIGHT + Height, 
        font = 'BOLD, 15', 
        compound = 'center', 
        image = PHOTO
        )
    
    BUTTON.place(
        x=(winWidth/2 - (BUTTON['width'])/2)+int(x),
        y=(winHeight/2 - (BUTTON['height'])/2-int(y)))

def Hi():
    print('hellow')

Create_Button('TheBUtton','Test', Hi() , 0, 0, 0, 0)

root.mainloop()
```

I thought the issue might be from the button function being full of variables, so that when it is pressed on the tkinter window, it can't recall what it needs to do. However I have no clue if this is how or why this is present. (let me know if this is the case, and if so how I would work around it or if I should try another thing)

All my different attempts ended with the same result as when I run the script, the button creation function runs, creating and placing a button, but also running the function what would run when the button is pushed (which shouldn't be happening normally), and then getting an unresponsive button on the tkinter window.

My expectation is for the Create_Button function to create and place a working button based on the arguments in the Create_Button function.

If there are other suggestions on how to reach the same result in a different method, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Try changing Hi() to Hi in `Create_Button('TheBUtton','Test', Hi() , 0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @Derek, what does that exactly change? I mean specifically how does that change how the code is interpreted?

Comment: By using 'hi()' instead of 'hi', you are actually calling function 'hi' and passing whatever 'hi' returns ( which is `None`).

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

winWidth = 500
winHeight = 500

HEIGHT = 30
WIDTH = 100
SIZE = 15

screeenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

cenX = int(screeenWidth/2 - winWidth/2)
cenY = int(screenHeight/2 - winHeight/2)

root.geometry(f'{winWidth}x{winHeight}+{cenX}+{cenY}')
root.title('Button Testing')

def Create_Button(BUTTON : str, Text : str, Command, Width : int, Height : int, x : int, y: int):
    BUTTON = Button(
        root, 
        text = Text, 
        command = Command, 
        font = 'BOLD, 15', 
        compound = 'center'
        )
    
    BUTTON.place(
        x=(winWidth/2 - (BUTTON['width'])/2)+int(x),
        y=(winHeight/2 - (BUTTON['height'])/2-int(y)),
        width = WIDTH + Width, 
        height = HEIGHT + Height)
    return BUTTON

def Hi():
    print('hellow')

btn_1 = Create_Button('TheBUtton','Test', Hi() , 10, 10, 10, 10)
btn_2 = Create_Button('TheBOOOOOUtton','not a test?', Hi() , 10, 10, 10, 100)
btn_1["text"] = "new text"
root.mainloop()
```

***I edited your code so it works now***

Okay, firstly I would recommend you put width and height in the `.place` file in your code since, when you put it in the button it accounts for the len and rows of the text, and not for the pixels.

ex
'''this
here'''
it's width is 4 and height is 2 (4 alphabets across and 2 rows)

And also I'm not understanding a lot in your program, like the pixels of the root and **Especially your code isn't working because the button is being huge since your adding 500 and it is inside the button not the `.place`
since width = WIDTH + Width, WIDTH=100 Width=0 that makes it 500 alphabets
and it is 30 for the height(rows)**

I also added a return func which makes you able to edit it in the future. And, maybe doing `anchor=tk.CENTER` in the `.place` will make it better imo but I didn't add that in the code.

Comment: OP code has an image in the button, so the `width` and `height` options are in pixels.

Comment: Yes, I designed it to be in pixels specifically. Thank you though. Could you elaborate on why you added the return button bit?